# Lifelog responding with ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

The page that is handling authentication for Sony Lifelog seems to have issues that makes it inaccessible. 
Neither of our applications (Both an Android app and a website) can get refresh-tokens nor  access-tokens; the only response we get is `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

Other people are experiencing it as well: https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Lifelog/Can-t-log-in-to-Lifelog/td-p/678295/page/2

[API status dashboard](https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/api-status-dashboard/) says the service is up, though I suspect that it only refers to the actual Lifelog data API and not the authentication service.

Is this a known issue? And are there any work-around for now?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? The authentication flow should be working.

Comment: @Robert-Sony It seems to have been resolved.